# Ajax form not rendering partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to implement a follow/unfollow form to create/destroy a relationship between a user, and a company on a site. I'm having problems rendering a new partial on form submit, to change the relationship button from "follow" to "unfollow"

Currently, I render a different partial depending on whether or not a relationship already exists:

```
`<% unless current_user.id == @company.user_id  %>
 <div id="#relationship">
    <% if current_user.following?(@company)  %>
      <%= render :partial => 'unfollow' %>
    <% else  %>
      <%= render :partial =>  'follow' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>`
```

The follow partial looks like:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @company.id), remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Follow",class: "btn-transparent btn-hollow btn-huge" %>
<% end %>
```

While the unfollow partial looks like:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.find_by(followed_id: @company.id), html: { method: :delete }, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn-transparent btn-hollow  btn-huge" %>
<% end %>
```

These use Create and Destroy methods in my Relationships_Controller:

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @company = Company.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@company)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @company }
      format.js {render layout: false}
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @company = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow!(@company)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @company }
      format.js{render layout: false}
    end
  end
end
```

If I set remote: false, the form works as expected, creating and destroying relationships, and the button changes on page reload. When I try to use AJAX by setting remote: true, and use the code below for relationships/create.js.erb and relationships/destroy.js.erb

```
$("#relationship").html("<%= j render('companies/unfollow') %>");

$("#relationship").html("<%= j render('companies/follow') %>");
```

However, now when I reload my page - I can click on the button once to create/destroy a relationship object. If I click again, I get a 500 error. The new partial is never loaded.

Although I'm a bit of a noob, this error in seems to point me to this line in the jquery source in chrome dev tools:

```
xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );
```

I'm using Rails 4, Jquery-Turbolinks and Devise - if any of them bare any relevance to the problem.

Incredibly frustrated now, if anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated!

**Update**

The log output is below. The first DELETE says that it has rendered my partial, however it has not. The second DELETE is what is happening on clicking unfollow a second time - it rightly points out that the Relationship with that id number no longer exists, as it was deleted on the first action.

```
Started DELETE "/relationships/429" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-28 14:34:59 +0000
Processing by RelationshipsController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "commit"=>"Unfollow", "id"=>"429"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mRelationship Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT  "relationships".* FROM "relationships"  WHERE "relationships"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 429]]
  [1m[36mCompany Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies"  WHERE "companies"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[35mRelationship Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT  "relationships".* FROM "relationships"  WHERE "relationships"."follower_id" = $1 AND "relationships"."followed_id" = 1 LIMIT 1  [["follower_id", 1]]
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (3.6ms)[0m  DELETE FROM "relationships" WHERE "relationships"."id" = $1  [["id", 429]]
  [1m[36m (0.5ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
  Rendered companies/_follow.html.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendered relationships/destroy.js.erb (5.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 19ms (Views: 7.0ms | ActiveRecord: 6.3ms)


Started DELETE "/relationships/429" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-28 14:35:04 +0000
Processing by RelationshipsController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "commit"=>"Unfollow", "id"=>"429"}
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.9ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mRelationship Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "relationships".* FROM "relationships"  WHERE "relationships"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 429]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 4ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Relationship with 'id'=429:
```

Comment: nice to see you console log for this error

Comment: I don't know if this is it, but it looks like you have an extra parenthesis in `$("#relationship").html("<%= j (render('companies/follow') %>");`. The console log would be great as well if this isn't the issue.

Comment: deleted that parentheses and it's still not working - it got stuck in there while I was trying lot of things. Updated with log output now.

Comment: yes, in the log file relationship with id 429 means that I've clicked that button 429 times trying to figure this out :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a hash in the name of your ID.

Try changing

```
<div id="#relationship">
```

to

```
<div id="relationship">
```

Answer (score 0):

When use `remote: true` you must change:

```
format.js{render layout: false}
```

with

```
format.js
```

Otherwise: you never render `relationships/create.js.erb` and `relationships/destroy.js.erb`